# Automatically replacing text in SublimeText via a plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have some HTML emails which have numbers that change in certain rows in every version. Ideally I would like to insert some tags in each section which will then be replaced with numbers based on data within a spreadsheet (or I could just put these numbers in the code, really). I am wondering where I can start to learn about creating a plugin which will be able to do this in SublimeText. I am sure I could do this by creating a website which would query a database, but I'd really like to create a sublime text plugin to accomplish this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Some reading perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

First off, Sublime Text 3 plugins are written in Python 3, so you'll need to be familiar with it to get anywhere.

You can start by reading the [documentation on plugins](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) , as well as the [plugins reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html) in the "unofficial" docs. Then, dive into the [official Sublime Text 3 API reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) and the supplemental [API reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/api.html) which details some things missing in the official docs. Finally, install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin and use it to extract the `Default` package, which contains the example plugins mentioned in the official API docs, as well as any other plugin packages you may have installed that you'd like to study. There are a number of plugin-related questions here on SO under [sublime-text-plugin](/questions/tagged/sublime-text-plugin), and the [forum](https://sublimetext.com/forum/) (if it's functional) has a lot of info as well, and is a great place to ask for advice.

Good luck!